# When grep "\\" XXFile I got "Trailing Backslash"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Now I want to find whether there are lines containing '\' character. I tried `grep "\\" XXFile` but it hints "Trailing Backslash". But when I tried `grep '\\' XXFile` it is OK. Could anyone explain why the first case cannot run? Thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe accept the answer to mark the question as resolved?

Comment: Both answers doesn't answer question. OP (and myself) wanted to search lines containing '\' (a single backslash). Both `grep '\' ...` and `grep "\\" ...` results in `grep: Trailing backslash`

Answer (score 114):

The difference is in how the shell treats the backslashes:

- When you write `"\\"` in double quotes, the shell interprets the backslash escape and ends up passing the string `\` to grep. Grep then sees a backslash with no following character, so it emits a "trailing backslash" warning. If you want to use double quotes you need to apply two levels of escaping, one for the shell and one for grep. The result: `"\\\\"`.
- When you write `'\\'` in single quotes, the shell does *not* do any interpretation, which means grep receives the string `\\` with both backslashes intact. Grep interprets this as an escaped backslash, so it searches the file for a literal backslash character.

If that's not clear, we can use `echo` to see exactly what the shell is doing. `echo` doesn't do any backslash interpretation itself, so what it prints is what the shell passed to it.

```
$ echo "\\"
\
$ echo '\\'
\\
```

Answer (score 7):

You could have written the command as

```
grep "\\\\" ...
```

This has two pairs of backslashes which bash will convert to two single backslashes. This new pair will then be passed to grep as an escaped backslash getting you what you want.

Comment: I'd call `grep '\\'` far easier to understand.