# List definitions of a single context

Tags: command-line, behat

Not sure if what I'm looking for is even possible.

I'm using behat, and we're several teams working in the same base code.
So there are a lot of sentence definitions that aren't interchangeable.

I would like to list the sentences by context, something like `behat -dl` but only fetching from a single context file (or even better if I could name a list of them).

Any idea if it's possible?

**Edit**: adding `behat -di` output

```
...
 Then /^the response status code should be (?P<code>\d+)$/
    - Checks, that current page response status is equal to specified.
    # FeatureContext::assertResponseStatus()

 Then /^the response status code should not be (?P<code>\d+)$/
    - Checks, that current page response status is not equal to specified.
    # FeatureContext::assertResponseStatusIsNot()

 Then /^(?:|I )should see "(?P<text>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
    - Checks, that page contains specified text.
    # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()

 Then /^(?:|I )should not see "(?P<text>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
    - Checks, that page doesn't contain specified text.
    # FeatureContext::assertPageNotContainsText()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no such solution out of the box. BUT! You can use `grep` functionality.
F.e.

```
./bin/behat -di
```

Will result you with expanded info about test steps:

```
TestSuite | When /^I am searching with "([^"]*)" text$/
          | at `Test\Context\FeatureContext::simpleSearch()`
```

So if you want to filter result by file you can use the next command:

```
./bin/behat -di| grep "Test\\\\Context\\\\FeatureContext"
```

**NOTE:** Backslash should be treated like this: `\\\\` because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342464/when-grep-xxfile-i-got-trailing-backslash)

**UPDATE** : Solution is applied only for Behat version > 3 with using Suites functionality.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. could it be because I'm using v2.4?

Comment: hm,  what exactly does not work? is `./bin/behat -di` produce output? if yes, then can you paste it and command which you are running with grep